# How do I set up alerts on AWS instances to let me know when my data analysis is complete?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've got a sizable data set that I'd like to analyze in the cloud. Since server costs are high for the top tier AWS instances, I'd like to receive an alert — preferably by email — when the computation is complete.

I'm relatively new to working with AWS, so was wondering what the best way to do so may be. Appreciate the input!

Comment: How are you doing your analysis? What systems are you using? Is it just your own code running on an Amazon EC2 instance, or are you using Amazon EMR, etc? Or are you simply asking how to send a notification and you'll figure out _when_ to send it separately?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It's my jupyter notebook code running on an EC2. It's large analysis, so I just want to be able to get an email notification when it's done — basically, as soon as it's finished, I'd like something to notify me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a message via Amazon SNS. You should be able to run shell commands from your Notebook.

To send an SMS message, use:

```
aws sns publish --phone-number +61123456789 --message 'Finished!'
```

To notify via other means:

- Create an **Amazon SNS topic**
- **Subscribe** to the topic using your preferred method (eg email)

Then, to send a message to the topic, which will then be forwarded to all subscribers:

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn XXX --subject 'Finished!' --message XXX
```